# SharePoint MOSS and .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, asp.net, sharepoint

Is .net 3.5 supported with MOSS 2007 Server? Anyone had any issues with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is fully supported.
[See Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751.aspx)

We have had no issues with it.

Answer (score 2):

We have been using 3.5 in very large MOSS environments since January of 2009 and in production since April. We have had no issues. I strongly recommend moving to 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

3.5 is a superset of 2, hence it's supported.

We have a working installation working with 3.5 but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

As a comment, keep in mind that in order to use the .net 3.5 special stuff from asp.net (ListView and LinqDataSource as an example) you have to modify your web.config to support .net 3.5

Up on codeplex there is such a feature available for download:

http://features.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2502#DownloadId=33434